# Compare String const value in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code in React Js but the flagImg is equal with the 2nd value (GRFlag). I think that is the way that I am trying to compare the 2 strings to the problem. Does anyone help?

```
const [lan ,setLan] = React.useState("GR");
const flagImg = {lan} === "GR" ? <UKFlag style={{width: "40px"}}/> : <GRFlag style={{width: "40px"}}/>;
```

Comment: Remove the `{ }` from `lan` when comparing. With those brackets you compare `{ lan: 'GR' } === "GR"`, which will never be `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [lan ,setLan] = React.useState("GR");
const flagImg = (lan === "GR" ? <UKFlag style={{width: "40px"}}/> : <GRFlag style={{width: "40px"}}/>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You compare an object with a string here, it is always false

```js
{lan} === 'GR'
```

This is what you need

```js
lan === 'GR'
```

Answer (score 1):

So

```
 {lan} === "GR"
```

Will actually compare an object with a key `lan` to a string 'GR' and that would result in `false` right because it's actually comparing `{lan: 'GR'} === 'GR'` . Remove those `{}` brackets and that should solve it for you.

```
lan === 'GR'
```